# Trying to append div - results in [object Object]

Tags: javascript, append

I'm trying to append a div, but it only appends a text string with [object Object]. So it appends something, but not the div I had in mind.

```
addMarker(){
            var x = this.$.carDialog;
                x.querySelector('.car-img-container').append(
                     $("<div></div>").css({
                         position: 'absolute',
                         top: MouseEvent.pageX + 'px',
                         left: MouseEvent.pageY + 'px',
                         width: '10px',
                         height: '10px',
                         zIndex: '5000',
                         background: '#ff0000'
                     })

                 );                
        }
```

Comment: Just don't mix vanilla JS with jQuery like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery and vanilla JavaScript for DOM manipulation. This is usually a bad idea.

Due to how you are creating your `<div>`, I'd just go all jQuery:

```
$(x).find('.car-img-container').append(/* div code here */);
```

If you use the one from `querySelector()`, that is expecting an actual `NodeElement`. When you give it the `jQuery`, that is an object, which gets cast as the string `[object Object]` and appended as a `TextNode`.

If you wanted to go that route, you could also use the `get(0)` function for jQuery:

```
x.querySelector('.car-img-container').appendChild($('<div></div>).get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I went with the first row, going all jquery!